# Getting ICLRRuntimeInfo instance is null C++

Tags: api, debugging, interop, clr

I'm getting ICLRRuntimeInfo instance is null C++

```
DWORD pid = 2076;
HRESULT hr;
HANDLE hProcess;
ICLRMetaHost  *pMetaHost = NULL;
IEnumUnknown *ppEnumerator = NULL;
ICLRRuntimeInfo  *CLRRuntimeInfo = NULL;
ULONG    pFetched = 0;
DWORD versionLength;

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

if (hProcess == NULL) {
  printf("process unable to open");
  return 0;
} 

hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost,*)&pMetaHost);
pMetaHost->EnumerateLoadedRuntimes(hProcess, &ppEnumerator);

if (ppEnumerator == 0) {
  return 0;
}

hr = ppEnumerator->Next(1, (IUnknown **)&CLRRuntimeInfo, &pFetched);
if (hr == S_FALSE) {
  printError(TEXT("CLRRuntimeInfo"));
  return 0;
}
```

When I tried with EnumerateInstalledRuntimes, got all installed Runtimes
    pMetaHost->EnumerateInstalledRuntimes( &ppEnumerator)
Windows error i got :failed with error 18 (There are no more files)

Answer (score 0):

In Project properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Dirctories-> $(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86

But I'm building solution with x64. Now changed to x86. working fine.